# T-SQL - JSON_QUERY : select json properties with special characters in the property name

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, json-query

I'm facing some issues while trying to select a value from a JSON column.
The json is:

```
{
    "$type":"myNameSpace.myClass, myDll"
}
```

And I'm trying to query it with something like

```
SELECT myIdColumnName, myJsonColumnName, JSON_QUERY(myJsonColumnName, '$.$type') as mType
```

the problem is that the path '$.$type' is invalid, the italian error is:

```
 Il formato del percorso JSON non è corretto. È stato trovato il carattere imprevisto '$' nella posizione 2.
```

which basically tells that the parser does not expect "$" after ".".
I already tried using '$.type' and '$."$type"' but it in both cases I get null as mType.

Could you tell me the right syntax for this query?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to extract `JSON` object or scalar value and your `path` begins with a dollar sign `$`, you need to surround it with quotes `"`. Function `JSON_QUERY` extracts an object or an array from a `JSON` string, so `JSON_VALUE` is more appropriate here when you want to extract a scalar value from `JSON` text.

Example:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "$type":"myNameSpace.myClass, myDll"
}'

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$."$type"')
```

Output:

```
--------------------------
(No column name)
--------------------------
myNameSpace.myClass, myDll
```